# Console.log returning undefined on ngOninit, but returning data on function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this problem, i want to print whatever the data is in userdata variable. but I only get an undefined text when making a console.log().

but when I place this console log inside a function and call it with a button it throws the actual data.
I tried to put the console.log inside a function and call it at the end of ngoinint but this does not work.

my code

```
public userData!: any;
    
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserData(this.userId);
    console.log(this.userData) //this prints undefined
    
}

getUserData(id: number) {
    this.userService.getUserData(id).subscribe((response) => {
        this.userData = response.data;
        this.userCategory = response.data.UsersCategory;
    });
}

this.printData(){
    // this only works if i press a button to call it 
    // but does not work if I call this function inside ngOnInit
    console.log(this.userData);
}
```

Comment: The ‘this.userData’ field doesn’t get set until the service returns data.

Comment: you have an async operation there on this variable - so it's not filled yet when you log it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your described goal**

*i want to print whatever the data is in userdata variable*.

> The moment you log `userData` is at the `ngOnInit`. At this time (lifecycle hook) the value has not been set yet.

**What could cause** `userData` **to be set?**

> `userData` is only set at only place in your code - inside the `subscription` that is within the `getUserData` function.

**Requirements to receive a value**

1. `getUserData` has to be called. That will create a `subscription`
2. `this.userService.getUserData(id)` has to emit at least one value

*Your code does neither show a* `getUserData` *call nor a observable emit* `this.userService.getUserData(id)` *is shown*.

**Misconcept**

Your code looks a lot like synchronuous imperative. Although RxJS is reactive and handles asynchronuous values for you. I think you have a missunderstanding of how RxJS is intended to be used. Some tips that might help

1. Try to subscribe as early as possible to observables

```
ngOnInit() {
   observable$.subscribe(value => userData = value)
}
```

2. If your observables *dont* cover all informations and events > create one with that fits your needs

```
private readonly getUserData$$ = new Subject()

getUserData(id: number) {
    this.getUserData$$.next(id)
}
```

3. Use the power of [rxjs operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators) to create a pipe that fits your needs

```
private readonly getUserData$$ = new Subject()

public userData: any;

ngOnInit() {
    getUserData$$.pipe(
        switchMap(id => this.userService.getUserData(id)
    ).subscribe(response => this.userData = response.data)
}

getUserData(id: number) {
    this.getUserData$$.next(id)
}
```

Comment: We have a vast number of questions about this issue, and the ways of dealing with it. We don't need more. If you think your answer adds something unique, add it to the duplicate question.

Comment: I dont see how your linked question refers to rxjs and asynchronuous operations? The undefined variable is just the end of an chain of possible issues. IMO the context and source of the problem is completely different to your linked one. Therefore in my eyes this questions and answer is valid and useful.  But maybe I understood the assignment wrong.